# OSStatus 560161140 when getting kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareInputNumberChannels

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audiounit

```
OSStatus status;
/******** Number of input channels ***************/
UInt32 inputchannels; 
UInt32 sizeofdata= sizeof(inputchannels); 
//problematic: gives number of potential inputs, not number actually connected
status= AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareInputNumberChannels,&sizeofdata,&inputchannels);
[self checkStatus:status]; //prints statement 1 if OSStatus !=0
NSLog(@"Inputs %d \n",inputchannels); //prints statement 2
```

Above code results in OSStatus 560161140 (statement 1)..... and  Inputs 0 (statement 2).

Any one please help me to know why i am getting this error status, what can it cause and how to prevent it........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Result Codes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007915-CH7a-SW1) section of the [Audio Session Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html):

```
560161140 == 0x21636174 == "!cat"
```

Which means:

> The specified audio session category cannot be used for the attempted
>   audio operation. For example, you attempted to play or record audio
>   with the audio session category set to
>   kAudioSessionCategory_AudioProcessing. Available in iOS 3.1 and later.

I can help you interpret the result but I cannot tell you the root cause.